# ACCESS: Compare numbers from different tables

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, ms-office

I don't know much Microsoft Access, but I need it to solve this issue:

Let's suppose that I have two tables:

Table A:

```
Zipcode Start | ZipCode End | Etc1          | Etc2
==============================================================
20000-000     | 29999-999   | Sample data 1 | Another Sample 1
30000-000     | 39999-999   | Sample data 2 | Another Sample 2
40000-000     | 49999-999   | Sample data 3 | Another Sample 3
```

Table B:

```
NAME     | ZipCode   |  Etc1   |    Etc2
=============================================
John Doe | 31564-888 |         |
Johnny   | 22559-010 |         |
James    | 44411-000 |         |
```

How can I compare the Zipcodes on **table B** with the specified ranges on table A? And return the "Etc1" and "Etc2" that matches it?

Thank you ALL!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
Select 
    TableB.Name,
    TableB.ZipCode,
    TableA.Etc1,
    TableA.Etc2
From
    TableA,
    TableB
Where
    TableB.ZipCode Between TableA.[ZipCode Start] And TableA.[ZipCode End]
```

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm. You solved in seconds something no one here could. Thank you!!

Comment: Oh, I think you underestimate my fellow members - like me, they can be busy having a life.

Comment: I meant here in my Office :P

Comment: I should have said that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Have a nice weekend!